# python cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> .I know the reason, but I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python

I need a reliable code, and I've done a lot of related tests, and it seems that it can only serialize the string and not serialize the sheet object

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import openpyxl


def proxy(cls_instance, index):
    return cls_instance.func(index)


class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, obtest, sheet):
        self.obtest = obtest
        self.sheet = sheet

    def func(self, index):
        return index


class OBTest(object):

    def run(self):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/attackt/Downloads/excelfile.xlsx')
        pool = Pool(processes=5)
        sheets = wb.worksheets
        # sheets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        result = []
        for index, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
            instance = Runner(self, sheet)
            result.append(pool.apply_async(proxy, (instance, index)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for data in result:
            print data.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OBTest().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a **call**() method inside your class Runner, If the class defines the **call** method, its instance can be invoked as a function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import openpyxl

def proxy(cls_instance, index):
    return cls_instance.func(index)


class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, obtest, sheet):
        self.obtest = obtest
        self.sheet = sheet

    def func(self, index):
        return index

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.func(x)


class OBTest(object):

    def run(self):
        #wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/attackt/Downloads/excelfile.xlsx')
        pool = Pool(processes=5)
        #sheets = wb.worksheets
        sheets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        result = []
        for index, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
            instance = Runner(self, sheet)
            result.append(pool.apply_async(proxy, (instance, index)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for data in result:
            print data.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OBTest().run()
```

-

Results:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Or you can use copy_reg

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import types
import copy_reg
import openpyxl


def _pickle_method(m):
    if m.im_self is None:
        return getattr, (m.im_class, m.im_func.func_name)
    else:
        return getattr, (m.im_self, m.im_func.func_name)


copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method)


def proxy(cls_instance, index):
    return cls_instance.func(index)


class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, obtest, sheet):
        self.obtest = obtest
        self.sheet = sheet

    def func(self, index):
        return index


class OBTest(object):

    def run(self):
        #wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/attackt/Downloads/excelfile.xlsx')
        pool = Pool(processes=5)
        #sheets = wb.worksheets
        sheets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        result = []
        for index, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
            instance = Runner(self, sheet)
            result.append(pool.apply_async(proxy, (instance, index)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        for data in result:
            print data.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OBTest().run()
```

--

```
im_self is the class instance object;
im_func is the function object;
im_class is the class of im_self for bound methods or the class that asked for the method for unbound methods;
```

--

### what can be pickled and unpickled

```
None, True, and False
integers, long integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
normal and Unicode strings
tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
functions defined at the top level of a module
built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
classes that are defined at the top level of a module
instances of such classes whose __dict__ or the result of calling 
__getstate__() is picklable (see section The pickle protocol for details).
```

--

### Please vote my answer, if my solution help you. Because I need to unlock my account! Thanks!

### Please see the following method!

```
def run(self):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/justTest/Downloads/outputlistmobile.xlsx')
    pool = Pool(processes=5)

    # sheets = wb.worksheets
    # # sheets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    result = []
    sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
    for index, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
        instance = Runner(self, sheet)
        result.append(pool.apply_async(proxy, (instance, index)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for data in result:
        print(data.get())
```

Comment: When the string is passed, there is no problem. The problem is to read the Excel

Comment: It can't be used in one piece with openpyxl

Comment: Less than 15 praise, audit but not display